# Python: copy files by iterating over 2 lists

Tags: python, arrays, file, io

I have created two arrays, and have python get user input to fill these arrays, like so:

```
#Establish the number directory paths
print "How many additional directories will you need to copy?"
dirCount = int(raw_input(prompt))
srcDirList = []
dstDirList = []
```

I would like to iterate over both of them and copy the data from the srcDirList into the corresponding value in dstDirList. I have set that up as so:

```
#iterate through both source and destination arrays and
#copy the additionally specified source directories to destination directories
for src, dst in zip(srcDirList, dstDirList):
    dir_copy(src, dst)
```

However, my script seems to just get stuck here. It doesn't copy like it's supposed to and it doesn't exit or throw an error. Do I have some sort of infinite loop? Is this just a terrible way of implementing this?

Edit: Here is the code for dir_copy:

```
#copy function
def dir_copy(srcpath, dstdir):
    #set destination dirname to share basename with the source directory
    dirname = os.path.basename(srcpath)
    #set the actual directory path
    dstpath = os.path.join(dstdir, dirname)
    shutil.copytree(srcpath, dstpath)
```

Comment: Could you please show the code for `dir_copy`?

Comment: Side-note: I suspect you'd probably be better off not reinventing the wheel, and just use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) instead of a roll-your-own version (and it will probably handle weird cases like symlinks and the like correctly, where you might not). Python's got batteries included, use them.

Comment: Both lists are empty in the code you've shown us. There is nothing to iterate and the for loop closes. The problem has to be in code you haven't shown us. How about print statements before, during and after the for loop for a better hint where the problem is?

Comment: @tdelaney the arrays are filled with directory paths input by the user (currently me)

Comment: The code you've shown is a reasonable implementation and should work. Sprinkle some print statements around or use a debugger to see where things go wrong.

Comment: @tdelaney any suggestions for a good python debugger? I don't have anything right now and could use some options.

Comment: Debuggers really help! I've used [eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), [komodo](http://komodoide.com/) (I bought this one) and of course [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html), the command line debugger that comes with python. [ipython](http://ipython.org/) looks very cool and probably has debugging but I'm not experienced with it.